# Rails cron not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I'm using the whenever gem to have a rails cron job send emails. Everything seems to work just fine and i have no errors in my cron.log or my production.log file, but i never receive an email. I've checked that the email address is correct also.

Any help is appreciated.

The production.log file contains this:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  Rendered email_mailer/send_birthday_reminders.html.erb (5.3ms)

Sent mail to tomcaflisch@gmail.com (409ms)
```

Here's my whenever gem schedule.rb file

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every :hour do
    runner "BirthdayRemindersController.send_birthday_email_reminders"
end
```

birthday_reminders_controller.rb

```
class BirthdayRemindersController < ApplicationController

    # cron job that sends birthday reminders
    def self.send_birthday_email_reminders 
        users = User.all

        email_addresses = []

        users.each_with_index do |user, i|
            if user.user_details.birthday_reminders == true
                email_addresses[i] = get_primary_email(user)
            end
        end
        p "email_addresses to send to:"
        p email_addresses

        users.each do |user|
            p "this user is"
            p user.user_details.full_name
            if user.user_details.birthday.try(:strftime, "%m") == Date.today.strftime("%m") && user.user_details.birthday.try(:strftime, "%d") == Date.today.strftime("%d")
                p "reminder sent"
                EmailMailer.send_birthday_reminders(user, email_addresses).deliver
            end
        end
    end
end
```

email_mailer.rb snippet

```
class EmailMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  default :from => "\"FamNFo\" <no-reply@mysite.com>"

  def send_birthday_reminders(birthday_person, email_addresses)
    p "we in send_birthday_reminders mailer"
    p email_addresses
    @birthday_person = birthday_person
    mail(:subject => "Birthday Reminder For The Caflisch Family", :to => email_addresses, :reply_to => email_addresses)
  end
end
```

capistrano's deploy.rb contains this

```
# needed for the 'whenever' gem
set(:whenever_command) { "RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec whenever"}
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

Comment: what are your smtp settings in production?

Comment: Your production log is showing that it is sending (unless @EfratBlaier is right, but since you responded, then I assume you've checked that). Have you checked sendmail's config and logs?

Comment: Where would the sendmail logs be located?

Comment: Oh my god i just checked my spam folder. The messages were getting sent there. I'm an idiot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your spam folder. To make sure emails don't end up there, add an "Unsubscribe" link in each email.

Answer (score 3):

This could happen if your action mailer configuration specifies perform_deliveries=false. You can check out the configuration in your environment files.

Comment: My app sends email just fine when not used in cron.

Comment: I would try to test that the whenever gem is working properly on your system.  My suspicion is that nothing is actually being run for whatever reason, which would explain the lack of errors.

Comment: Except all my puts statements are being called in my controller method and my mailer method so the whenever gem is working fine

Answer (score 1):

If your application is deployed to cloud services then you may be getting your emails in a spam folder. Their entire IP blocks are registered as spam at services like `Spamhaus`, which is a sensible precaution or else we'd be getting even more spam than usual.

You should enter your server's IP address in that field to see if you're listed as a spammer.

If you are, you can request to Spamhaus that the block be lifted.

Comment: I'm using a media temple (dv). It's a VPS so i don't think that's what you mean by a cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

The other big issues I have found is that the PATH and rbenv may not be initialized in the CRONTAB depending on how you have it setup.
I would recommend adding the following to the top of your `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

This ensures that if you are using `whenever` to call model methods that `rbenv` and `ruby` are fully available.